# How to create a view to refine data from Customer Meter data on ORACLE

Tags: oracle, view, plsql

I have a METER_DATA table or ORACLE contains information

[METER_DATA data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN6LG.png)

I want to refine data base on SAMPLE_TIME with rule minute = 0 or 30 only (so if Minute >= 30 then Min = 30; else minute = 0). For examples:

```
+ 6/28/2016  12:00:12 -> 6/28/2016  12:00:00
+ 6/28/2016  12:20:12 -> 6/28/2016  12:00:00
+ 6/28/2016  12:30:00 -> 6/28/2016  12:30:00
```

How can I create a VIEW using PL/SQL that got results:

[RESULTS data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORqst.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your sample RESULTS you simply copied the rows from 12:00:00 and 12:30:00 and deleted the rows (readings) from 12:15:00 and 12:20:00. Is that what you wanted? Or did you, instead, want to add together the readings from 12:00, 12:15 and 12:20 and label the sum as "12:00"? (And, I assume you would need to add the values separately for VAL1, VAL2 and VAL3). OR: possibly "max" or "min" of the readings (or "average") rather than "sum"? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks. But I only want to distinct and get results from one view, not delete data from Electric Meter. We expect 48 records per meter / day.

Comment: Still not clear. You have two readings, at 12:00 and at 12:15, and the readings on VAL1 are 1.2 and 1.6. In the result set, you want only one row for 12:00. What do you want to show for VAL1? Just the earliest value, 1.2? Or the AVERAGE of the readings? the SUM? the highest, or the lowest, or what? Your Comment does not answer this question.

Comment: Thanks ! We want to display customer energy usage each 30 minutes / day on dashboard. The meter automatically send data via 3G to database, but it send multiples rows than we expected, so we want to refine at get one record to display.

Comment: OK - so: In your example, you really don't need the readings from 12:15 and 12:20 at all; they will not be in the view. Then: Are you guaranteed that there will be at least one reading in each 30 minute interval? And that there will never be TWO readings at exactly the same time?

Comment: The data from meter transfer via 3G may loss or duplicate. Maybe it less than 48 records, maybe it more than 48 records. So we must refine and find one by one from a bunch of data to get results. Thanks again !

Comment: So, what do you do if: (1) You have two readings, with different values, at 12:30? Which do you use? (2) You have no readings between 12:20 and 1:45? What should be shown to the customer for 12:30 and 1:00?

Comment: Thanks ! (1) we can choose one from two records, maybe the first, no problem ! (2) If we have no readings between 12:20 and 1:45, we can estimate later or doesn't display loss data. Sample display:  http://dc738.4shared.com/img/WTF4F7Qrba/s23/1559cabd9a0/Screen_Shot_2016-06-29_at_2157

Comment: I edited the solution and added code to address the additional clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to truncate the server_time in order to obtain the sample_time depends on the data type.

If `server_time` is a **timestamp**, then Gordon offered one possible solution. It can be simplified somewhat as follows:

```
select systimestamp as system_timestamp,
       trunc(systimestamp, 'hh') 
            + case when extract(minute from systimestamp) < 30 then 0 else 1/48 end 
          as refined_timestamp
from dual;
```

The "1/48" has to do with the fact that we are truncating to half-hours, and date and timestamp arithmetic works in units of days. 30 minutes = 1/48 days.

Result:

```
SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP                         REFINED_TIMESTAMP
--------------------------------------   -------------------
29-JUN-16 08.03.43.591000000 AM -05:00   29-06-2016 08:00:00
```

Alas, this solution does not work if `server_time` has data type **date**, because `extract(... from some_date)` interprets `some_date` as an ANSI date, which only has year, month, day components (no hour, minute, second). See the Oracle documentation for `extract()`. (If you think this is idiotic on Oracle's part, I won't disagree!)

So you need a different solution. For example:

```
select sysdate as system_time,
       trunc(sysdate) + floor((sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 48) / 48 as refined_time
from   dual;
```

Result:

```
SYSTEM_TIME          REFINED_TIME
-------------------  -------------------
29-06-2016 08:15:13  29-06-2016 08:00:00
```

This solution, unfortunately, will only work for data type "date" and will not work for "timestamp". This is because, in Oracle, the difference between two dates is a number (in days) and you can do simple arithmetic. If you try to use a similar formula for timestamps, it won't work because the difference between two timestamps is not a number, but an interval, and the arithmetic as written doesn't work.

So: You will have to use one or the other, based on the actual data type of `system_time` in your table.

With all this said, here is a solution for your original problem, assuming that `system_time` is a date (date/time), not a timestamp, and assuming for each time interval you want to **average** the readings. If you wanted to add them up, or take the max or min, you should be able to adjust the solution yourself.

```
with meter_data (meter_id, server_time, val1, val2, val3) as (
       select 'A9000', to_date('6/28/2016 12:00 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM'), 
                      1.11, 2.11, 3.11 from dual union all
       select 'A9000', to_date('6/28/2016 12:15 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM'), 
                      1.12, 2.12, 3.12 from dual union all
       select 'A9000', to_date('6/28/2016 12:20 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM'), 
                      1.13, 2.13, 3.13 from dual union all
       select 'A9000', to_date('6/28/2016 12:30 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM'), 
                      1.2 , 2.2 , 3.2  from dual
     ),
     prep_data (meter_id, val1, val2, val3, refined_time) as (
       select meter_id, val1, val2, val3,
              trunc(server_time) + floor((server_time - trunc(server_time)) * 48) / 48 
       from   meter_data
     )
select   meter_id, refined_time, 
         avg(val1) as avg_val1, avg(val2) as avg_val2, avg(val3) as avg_val3
from     prep_data
group by meter_id, refined_time
order by meter_id, refined_time
;
```

Result:

```
METER REFINED_TIME   AVG_VAL1   AVG_VAL2   AVG_VAL3
----- ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
A9000 2016-06-28         1.12       2.12       3.12
A9000 2016-06-28          1.2        2.2        3.2
```

... and as you can see, I am slave to my NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, so REFINED_TIME doesn't show the time. So I must wrap it within `to_char()` like so:

```
with meter_data (meter_id, server_time, val1, val2, val3) as (
       ........
     ),
     prep_data (meter_id, val1, val2, val3, refined_time) as (
       select meter_id, val1, val2, val3,
              trunc(server_time) + floor((server_time - trunc(server_time)) * 48) / 48 
       from   meter_data
     )
select   meter_id, to_char(refined_time, 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi AM') as refined_time,
         avg(val1) as avg_val1, avg(val2) as avg_val2, avg(val3) as avg_val3
from     prep_data
group by meter_id, refined_time
order by meter_id, refined_time
;
```

Results:

```
METER REFINED_TIME        AVG_VAL1   AVG_VAL2   AVG_VAL3
----- ----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A9000 06/28/16 12:00 PM       1.12       2.12       3.12
A9000 06/28/16 12:30 PM        1.2        2.2        3.2
```

**Added based on further clarification:**

To display just the first reading from each 30 minute interval, you can use

```
with meter_data (meter_id, server_time, val1, val2, val3) as (
       ................
     ),
     prep_data (meter_id, val1, val2, val3, refined_time, rn) as (
       select meter_id, val1, val2, val3,
              trunc(server_time) + floor((server_time - trunc(server_time)) * 48) / 48,
              row_number() over (partition by meter_id order by server_time)
       from   meter_data
     )
select   meter_id, refined_time, 
         min(val1) keep (dense_rank first order by rn) as val1,
         min(val2) keep (dense_rank first order by rn) as val2,
         min(val3) keep (dense_rank first order by rn) as val3
from     prep_data
group by meter_id, refined_time
order by meter_id, refined_time
;
```

Note that `val1` (for example) will be the `val1` for the earliest reading in a given 30 minute interval, NOT the minimum reading in the interval. In most cases, the earliest reading is unique, so `min` will have no effect as it is applied to just one value. HOWEVER, if there is more than one reading with exactly the same `system_time` (for example two readings at 12:00), then `min` will have an effect; it will select the smallest of the two values. Perhaps the business rules require to take the average in that case. If so, change `min(val1)` to `avg(val1)` and similar for `val2` and `val3`.

This solution does not address the case when there are no readings from 12:20 to 1:45 (so there are no values for 12:30 and 1:00); OP needs to explain the business rules for this possibility.

Comment: This is a good solution and nearly finish ! Please tell me how to get one record from first three to make billing. The customer will complain if we choose AVG, MAX or MIN when they reference data on meters. It's not exactly what he see. I expect one row from three. Thanks again !

Comment: Please explain HOW you get one record from the first three. It is not average of the three readings, or max, or anything else. What should it be? I don't know your business, how should I know what one number should be the result when the inputs are three numbers?

Comment: The first record that we found when refined_time is OK @mathguy. Thanks again !

Comment: It's OK. Thank you very much, @mathguy ! I also would like to thank Linoff too !

Answer (score 0):

One method is to truncate to the hour and then add the minutes back:

```
select trunc(sample_time, 'HH') + (trunc(extract(minute from sample_time) / 30) * 30) / 60*24
```

Comment: This assumes sample_time has data type "timestamp". In Oracle you can't extract (minute from sample_time) if sample_time is of data type "date."

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I want to distinct to get only one record from first three records. How can I get the final view for report purpose. Please reference results expecting !